# Finding a limit with squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a_n={\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}+{\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2}}}_{....}{\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}  $

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

I know the limit is zero. I also know that I need to use the squeeze theorem to solve it.

Now using ${\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}\le a_n \le {\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}$ as my upper and lower bounds doesn't yield 0, it yields 1.

It doesn't seem right but can I just use ${\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}\le a_n \le {\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}$ to solve ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the sequence: how does it "go" from $\;\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\;$ until $\;\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\;$ ??

Comment: Why do you think that the limit is zero?

Comment: What's inside the the $\sqrt {}$ is increasing by one each time. @njguliyev because the denominator is approaching infinity and one over infinity is zero.

Comment: The limit is not 0

Comment: @freak_warrior, are you sure ? the limit can be the sum of all the elements, if all the elements approach zero then the limit is zero.

Comment: I like how your right-handed side of the definition of $a_n$ does not contain n... Nicely defined sequence!

Comment: I edited the question for the OP @Inwvr

Comment: @lnwvr I know right ? Thanks freak_warrior, for the answer as well.

Comment: So many comments...and I still cannot understand how the sequence is defined!

Comment: "What's inside the the √ is increasing by one(+1) each time."

Comment: ...and what's therelation between $\,x\,$% and $\,n\,$ ? Or should they both be the same?

Comment: It was an error, it's now fixed.

Comment: Then your inequalities with $\;a_n\;$ , and also in the accepted answer (!) , are wrong!

Comment: And why is it wrong ?

Comment: Oh, dear! Because $\;\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\ge\sqrt{n^2+1}\;$ ...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not 0, in fact you are almost there!

${\frac {n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}}\le a_n \le {\frac {n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}}$

For LHS, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}}=1$.

For RHS, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}=1$

Hence, by Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$

Comment: But every element is zero as x approach infinity so the sum of all the zeros should be zero...

Comment: That's the wrong concept, it's like you are having infinitely many pieces of bits!

Comment: This is a mess, from the original post: the first inequality (with $\;a_n\;$) is completely wrong, of course.

Comment: @DonAntonio edited again! should be ok

Comment: The inequalities **still** are wrong, @freak_warrior...! $$\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\ge\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\ldots !$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Haha the idea is there. @DonAntonio

Comment: Well, that in fact is true, @freak_warrior...yet we must get used to be way more careful with these things of basic algebra.